# A question regarding matchings in bipartite graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph with $V(G)=X\cup Y$, let $M_1$ be a matching that "covers" $X'\subseteq X$, and let $M_2$ be a matching that "covers" $Y'\subseteq Y$.

Show that then there is a matching $M$ that "covers" $X'\cup Y'$.

It is natural to look for such a matching in the graph induced by $M_1\cup M_2$. This graph is a disjoint union of even-length cycles and paths as all vertices are of degree $1$ or $2$. Cycles and paths of even length obviously have a perfect matching. The problem is with paths of odd length --- any hints on how to handle this case?

Different proofs are welcome as well of course.

Comment: Part (b) of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1268005/extending-matchings-in-a-bipartite-graph . But I also remember seeing (either on m.se or on MO) a slicker proof, using Tarski's (?) fixed point theorem.

Comment: Another link (still not the slick proof): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1188829/union-of-two-matching-sets-being-a-matching?rq=1

Comment: Ah, here is the slick proof: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/203725/an-unfair-marriage-lemma

Comment: That's a lot of proofs. :) Thanks.

Comment: And if you prefer a hint rather than the whole solution, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/329852/26306).